# yum update and downgrade packages

Tags: upgrade, updates, yum, dependencies, downgrade

I have two bundles: bundle 7.5.0.0.0.14 and bundle 7.5.0.0.0.11

Each one contains a bunch of .rpms, with dependencies.

bundle 7.5.0.0.0.14 is an updated version of bundle 7.5.0.0.0.11,
except for one .rpm package which is older: fpga-fw-elic. This means: 
In `7.5.0.0.0.14` i have `fpga-fw-elic.1.7.1.rpm` 
&
In `7.5.0.0.0.11` i have `fpga-fw-elic.1.7.5.rpm` 
(It's like cross hands)

When i try to go downgrade from 14 to 11 , it works fine, and i get all the rpms donwgraded using the command `yum downgrade -y * --verbose --downloadonly`
But when i try to go upgrade from 11 to 14, i get missing dependencies that cannot be ressolved. i use the command: `yum update -y * --verbose  --downloadonly`.

How can I resolve this issue? of course i can downgrade to `fpga-fw-elic.1.7.1.rpm` first and install it, then i can use `yum update -y * --verbose  --downloadonly` without any problem, BUT i don't want to install any RPM yet.

please, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `-y` from your yum command so yum will do all the dependency checking and then it will prompt you for whether to go ahead with the update or not.